# Upgrading git on debian 7

Tags: git, debian

I am following this guide:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-git-on-debian-7

to upgrade git on a debian 7 machine.

Now I accidentally ran (as root):

```
sudo make prefix=/usr/local install
```

before (as normal user):

```
make prefix=/usr/local all
```

As a result I am still using the old version of git on the machine. If I try to run:

```
make prefix=/usr/local all
```

I get:

```
:~/tmp/git-1.8.5.5$ make prefix=/usr/local all
        GEN perl/PM.stamp
        SUBDIR gitweb
        SUBDIR ../
    make[2]: `GIT-VERSION-FILE' is up to date.
        GEN git-instaweb
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create GIT-BUILD-OPTIONS: Permission denied
    make: *** [GIT-BUILD-OPTIONS] Error 2
```

How do I *revert* this so I can upgrade git?

Comment: `sudo chown -R youruserid:yourgroup your/src/git`

Comment: Yes that was the solution. Leave it as an answer if you like.